# Oracle TABLE_PRIVILEGES Column Explanation

Tags: sql, oracle11g, data-dictionary

I queried the data dictionary `TABLE_PRIVILEGES` for one my user table to check the grants. It listed me 34 rows out of which for some of the records the value of `SELECT_PRIV` column is `Y` and for few of them it's `G`. I believe `Y` stands for `YES` but I am not clear on the `G` value. Can anyone please explain me what's does `G` mean here?

```
SELECT owner, 
       table_name, 
       select_priv, 
       insert_priv, 
       delete_priv, 
       update_priv, 
       references_priv, 
       alter_priv, 
       index_priv 
FROM table_privileges
WHERE grantee = <SCHEMA_NAME>
ORDER BY owner, table_name
```

Comment: Which dictionary _view_ are you talking about?

Comment: I will give you the query :
SELECT owner, table_name, select_priv, insert_priv, delete_priv, update_priv, references_priv, alter_priv, index_priv 
  FROM table_privileges
 WHERE grantee = <SCHEMA_NAME>
 ORDER BY owner, table_name

The name of the dictionary is itself TABLE_PRIVILEGES

Comment: **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Edited..Thanks..will take care next time.

Comment: That is an undocumented view. Why are you using it? [Quote from the 9i manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/server.901/a90190/ch2375.htm#984078) "*Oracle Corporation recommends that you do not use this view.*"

Comment: See this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/318752

Comment: Not pretty sure. Actually I got that from Stack Overflow only. Anyways I got the answer it stands for 'G' Grant Option.

Comment: Thanks...for the help...:)

Answer (score 0):

G Stands for grant.  It allows the grantee to grant others privileges on a given table

see: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm